# Word directly shows next table number while adding table caption

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a document in two column format. To insert table (or figure), I first insert a textbox and then inside the textbox, I insert a table (or a figure). Then finally, I right click the table (or a figure) > Insert caption... which opens following form:

[image]

Notice that the number 4 is pre populated by the Word and I cannot delete. There is currently only one table before this table and has a caption Table 1. There are other tables too which earlier had a caption, but now I have deleted them and now I want to reassign caption. But somehow, Word is pre populating the Table caption with some gap in the numbering sequence. Visually there is no table 2 and 3 in the word doc, but somewhere internally Word seem might have kept record for them and thus, it is now pre populating Table 4 while doing Insert Caption. How do I fix this?

PS: Am on MS Word 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous captions are still in your document somewhere.
The numbering of a Caption is controlled by a [SEQ field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-seq-sequence-field-062a387b-dfc9-4ef8-8235-29ee113d59be?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

### You can reset the number of your latest table to two.

If you Toggle display of the Field code (Shift+F9 or Alt+F9) you should see:

- `Table { SEQ Table \* ARABIC }`

Change that to `Table { SEQ Table \r 2 \* ARABIC }`

This resets the numbering of the Table series. Future tables added later in the document will pick up from that. Ones inserted before will require rewriting things again.

### Better would be to find the errant captions.

You likely can do that by displaying the Selection Pane and finding them. They are likely underneath some other figure or off screen. The selection pane can be displayed using the Select drop-down on the Home tab.

Here is a link to [my writing on Captions](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#Caption).

Comment: Yes. It turned out that I have two captions associated with the same figure!!! And some figures were hidden. I simply [generated list of tables and figures](https://www.officetooltips.com/word_365/tips/how_to_create_table_of_figures_and_list_of_tables.html) which showed where each of those tables were.